# I keep getting this error in javascript? (radio, checking them in javascript)

Tags: javascript, radio-button, checked

For some reason I keep getting this error, I don't know why.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of null js.js:4
check js.js:4
(anonymous function)
```

Here is my code:

```
document.body.onload="check()";
function check()
{
document.getElementById("urlchoice").checked=true;
}
```

Comment: I suppose it's probably something stupid, I have been really off today..sleep deprevation -.-

Comment: What does your radio group (html) look like?

Comment: I wonder why your error says "(anonymous function)" since it looks like the offending function is named `check`.

Comment: The syntax seems unnatural, should it be "document.body.onload=function (){ check(); }"

Comment: @user1420493: Don't use `eval` for this, follow **Xinus** advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if `document.getElementById("urlchoice")` is `null` or not.

```
    window.onload = check;

    function check(){
        if(document.getElementById("urlchoice")!=null){ // available
           document.getElementById("urlchoice").checked = true; 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an element with the ID `urlchoice` (whose absence would be trivial to diagnose, but I don't think that is causing your problem because you say that `check` is getting called), try `window.onload`, not `document.body.onload`.

**EDIT**

Again, assuming the document has a radio button element with id = `urlchoice`, and that the script is properly invoked and is running,

Try:

```
function check() {
    document.getElementById("urlchoice").checked=true;
}
window.onload=check;
```

or

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("urlchoice").checked=true;
}
```

These really should work.

Comment: I tried that just now, the code I first posted here I guess wasn't giving errors, but it just isn't checking the radio box for some stupid reason -.-

Answer (score 0):

the error points for an unidentifed element with id "urlchoice", are you sure it exists?

```
<body>    
    <input id="urlchoice" type="radio">

    <script>
        document.body.onload = check();
        function check(){        
            document.getElementById("urlchoice").checked=true;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

seems to work (i removed the double quotes of **the document.body.onload = check();** line, it don't work with it

Comment: Remove the `()` for the call to `check`. Setting `onload` shouldn't be a function call, just a reference to a function.